# Technique to kill the painted trolls

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I keep getting obliterated by the painted trolls in the painted forest.  I blow through the turpentine in no time with little effect.  Do they have another weakness?  Or is there another trick to killing them?

Comment: @Alastair: bah, there goes my taxonomist badge for oblivion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found I could find specific spots standing on rocks in the area where I could shoot at them from range and they could not hit me. Finding one of those locations and using ranged attacks might be your best bet if you're having trouble.

Comment: Yeah, standing on rocks is the way to go if you're squishy. Blow through all your mana fireballing them, loot corpse and wait for mana to recharge, repeat.

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it.  Loaded up on different types of arrows and fireball spells.  Found a good spot on the rocks and used sneak attacks with my bow that does fire damage.

Answer (score 3):

Your level shouldn't matter: According to the [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Painted_Troll), painted trolls are leveled, and have 25 HP per character level.

Trolls (including painted ones) do hate fire (50% weakness according to the [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Painted_Troll)), so consider fire magicka or fire-enchanted weaponry if it's available.

Me, I just hacked them to pieces, blocking where necessary. Each of them is in his own area, so you should never get gang-mauled by them.

You can also consider sneak attacks, if you see them in advance and are a bow user.

Finally, they do have regeneration abilities.

Comment: I'm high-level (clearing out some questions before entering the final stage of the main questline).  I think I remember reading somewhere that they're levelled creatures and as such get more difficult at higher levels.  I'm an assassin so the hack and slash thing typically backfires for me!

Comment: @squill: They are leveled -- 25 health per your level. If you're high-enough of a level and playing as an assassin, you want ranged attacks. Move backward in a zig-zag while shooting them down.